# c++ sleep taking too much CPU usage

Tags: c++, c

I am noob in c++; I have a problem. I am using:

```
while(true) { 
      doSomething(); 
      Sleep(time);
}
```

...in a thread and my program is taking high CPU because of the sleep itself (it checked and it must be the problem). Is there any way to use something else?

Comment: How did you check that it's the sleep and not the "doSomething()"?

Comment: Because high usage is even when thread is sleeping. time is currently set to 10 mins

Comment: What platform is this and what value did you use for `time`?

Comment: How long are you sleeping for? Maybe it's too short of a period to be accurately measured.

Comment: I am checking it on windows 7. Time is 600000 - 10 min

Comment: Also, doSomething is doing something for very short period of time - few seconds.

Comment: So what happens when you comment out `doSomething()`?

Comment: Since this code is in a thread, what are your other threads doing?  They also add to CPU time.

Comment: Please just post a [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org). There's no point in anyone even bothering to look at this if we can't see what you see.

Comment: Most of the program is hidden for me. I know that with adding this part of the program(loop), cpu usage is increasing a lot. I am also not sure if its not a main thread is it going on.

Comment: Windows API doesn't provide a function named `sleep`. It provides a function named `Sleep`. What is this `sleep` you are calling?

Comment: A thread does not use any CPU cycles while it is sleeping (especially when it is sleeping for 10 minutes at a time). That is the whole point of putting a thread to sleep - it gives up its remaining time slices and is not scheduled to run on the CPU again until after the sleep elapses.  On the other hand, calling a short-running `doSomething()` in a loop, especially if you comment out the sleep, is more likely to hit the CPU with high usage.

Answer (score 2):

"Sleep()" does not consume CPU - aside from the invocation overhead.

A likely cause is that you have other threads spinning. This can happen if you are using something like OpenMP or Intel's Thread Building Blocks; during the Sleep the worker-threads used by these systems continually poll for work to do resulting in a high CPU usage.

Or you have a worker thread of your own which is spinning CPU waiting for work to be delivered.